# AngularJS get form empty data too

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

i am trying to save a form data with angularjs into a database using php as backend. I have this html as the form

```
<form ng-submit="newContactSubmit()">
        <label>FirstName<input type="text" name="contact_firstname" required ng-model="newContact.contact_firstname" /></label>
        <label>LastName<input type="text" name="contact_lastname" ng-model="newContact.contact_lastname" /></label>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
```

Now the problem is lastname is not required in my case and if i send the form without filling anything in lastname, than the `newContact` variable has only the `contact_firstname` field which makes it do an error on the php side.

```
$scope.newContactSubmit = function() {
    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.newContact));
    /*contactService.saveContact($scope.newContact).then(function(response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    });*/
};
```

The controller doesnt send the `contact_lastname` field as empty. Is there a way to make it define both variables even if i dont complete them ? Thank you, Daniel!

Comment: What should be the value of the empty key? `null`?

Comment: yes or just empty string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about predefining default value for `contact_lastname`?

```
// inside your controller
$scope.newContact.contact_lastname = '';
```

so that `newContact` always has `contact_lastname` default value, even the field is left untouched.

Comment: this could be a solution, i asked because i tought there is a mor native solution to this which i dont know :)

Comment: If you map ``ng-model`` to a variable that is not (yet) defined inside your controller, its value is ``undefined`` until user interacts with it. So you have to either define its default value or tolerate its non-existence from server-side.